# Disable symfony application during maintenance

Tags: symfony, redirect, blocked

I'm looking for any way to disabled a Symfony application during maintenance support. I mean, in a very simple way:

1) I have a application where people can enter to see the info of the database.

2) The admin could change the info of the database. During this period of time, the database info should not be accesible because it has been deleting and updating.

3) What I want is, if there is any way to block the application during this maintenance period and redirect users (not the admin user) to a maintenance notice page.

I remember there was a global function which redirect all urls, but I don't remember very well.
During the maintenance period I could stablish a param in the Database (or in any other way), and ask for this value to know if the application is in maintenance period or not, to redirect to the normal url o redirect to the notive maintenance page.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please have a loot at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you store a param in the database to know if the admin is updating data then its fairly simple to use a kernel request listener:

- Test on the database value
- If Admin is the current user

[see here : Events and event listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html)

Comment: Hi Youssef, I have been trying this way and its work, but my question if is reasonable to have and event listener for each redirect in the page, I mean in terms of performance. This way needs to access the Database foreach redirect in the page. Could I save this param in any param of the application to not make a consult to the Database in each redirect? I thought in any param of the parameter,yml, but, could I change this value direct from the web interface?

Comment: You can write the value in something like Redis for example if you're already using it, then when the admin is done updating the database you just update the Redis value, in case you're not using Redis or something similar, storing the value in the database should be OK

Comment: One question... how can I throw a custon "exception" html page? I tried the event listener, but at the end it was impossible, because in the event listener I redirect a controller to print the maintenance.html.twig, but in this redirect, the event listener is called recursively....

Comment: You can just test on the route at the beginning of your listener, if it matches your error action's route then you don't do anything if not you apply the default processing.

Comment: I get it!! This way: in the event listener i don't call the controller to redirect, but return a response with the twig template:        
    $vistaMantenimineto = $this->container->get('templating')->render('AppBundle:Default:mantenimiento.html.twig');
    $event->setResponse(new Response($vistaMantenimineto));

Comment: Could you write me the solution you mean in your last post, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without changing any of the project code, directly in the webserver config. The following works on NGINX (but use with caution, because [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)) and it should be no problem to reproduce it for Apache.

```
location / {

  # if the user is not you / an admin
  if ($remote_addr != "your.ip.address") {
    # return http code 503 (The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance).)
    return 503;
  }

  # otherwise, go ahead as usual
  try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php?$is_args$args;

}

# show specific page when http code 503
error_page 503 @maintenance;
location @maintenance {
  # which is maintenance.html
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
}
```

IP check was a quick solution in my case. You could also check for specific cookies, etc. The idea stays the same: the application is independent of this.